# Page_load filling data after loading UserControl ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, ascx, pageload

I have an aspx Page that contain a userControl that contains textboxes.

in the page_load method, it reads from the database, and i want to fill the textboxes of the usercontrol with the data been read.

the problem i am facing, that the flow of page loading is

Page_Load of the page, where i am assigning the text field, then it page_load of the userControl, so here all the data will be erased, then it will show the page.

how i can fix this.

Comment: Don't use the UserControl's Load method to initiliaze it but the page's Page_Load. You should provide public properties in your UserControl to get/set your TextBoxes' Text property from the controller(page).

Comment: actually its a big project, and am not the one who made the usercontrol, so i dont know what could happen in case of i stop the load from the usercontrol. and i am required to use it :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case, you have to fill the data of UserControl in Page_Init not Page_Load, the problem here will be solved :)

Answer (score 0):

use OnDataBinding or OnPreRender